# Printed length in Layouts package inaccurate?

Tags: lengths

From the [layouts](https://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package manual (page 3 and 4):

> `The textwidth is \printinunitsof{pt}\prntlen{\textwidth} which is also
>   \printinunitsof{in}\prntlen{\textwidth} or
>   \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\textwidth}.`
>   prints out:
>  
>   The textwidth is 433.62pt which is also 6.00117in or 152.39821mm.

But 1 inch = 25.4 mm, so 6.00117in should equal 152.429718mm. I noticed this type of inaccuracy also in a document I am currently preparing.
The number of decimals provided in the manual example seems to imply a high accuracy, but practice seems to show otherwise.
Am I seeing/doing something wrong?
If not, how accurate are the printed lengths?

Comment: Rounding errors.

Comment: How accurate are the printed lengths then? N.B.: the manual is treacherous then with its many decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point calculations in `layouts` are based on dimension arithmetic of TeX, which is not really accurate.

You get better results with the floating point module of `expl3`. Still not accurate to five decimals, but much more than the coarser result by `layouts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layouts}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\prntlen}{m}
 {
  \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #1 } { 1\use:c {l@yunits} } \, \use:c{l@yunits}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}

\begin{document}

The textwidth is \printinunitsof{pt}\prntlen{\textwidth}
which is also \printinunitsof{in}\prntlen{\textwidth} or
\printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\textwidth}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is sufficient precise now for my purposes. Within my view, your answer would be a good improvement for a new version of the layouts package.